# In what order we need to put weights on scale?

Tags: math, combinatorics

I' am doing my homework in programming, and I don't know how to solve this problem:

We have a set of n weights, we are putting them on a scale one by one until all weights is used. We also have string of n letters "R" or "L" which means which pen is heavier in that moment, they can't be in balance. There are no weights with same mass. Compute in what order we have to put weights on scale and on which pan.

The goal is to find order of putting weights on scale, so the input string is respected.

Input: number 0 < n < 51, number of weights. Then weights and the string.

Output: in n lines, weight and "R" or "L", side where you put weight. If there are many, output any of them.

Example 1:

Input:

```
3
10 20 30
LRL
```

Output:

```
10 L
20 R
30 L
```

Example 2:

Input:

```
3
10 20 30
LLR
```

Output:

```
20 L
10 R
30 R
```

Example 3:

Input:

```
5
10 20 30 40 50
LLLLR
```

Output:

```
50 L
10 L
20 R
30 R
40 R
```

I already tried to compute it with recursion but unsuccessful. Can someone please help me with this problem or just gave me hints how to solve it.

Comment: "There is no situation when scale is in balance. Compute in what order we have to put weights on scale."  To accomplish what, what is the objective?  In your sample input and output, it looks like it's just transposing your inputs and echoing them back to you.

Comment: Your problem description is much better now, so I have retracted my vote to close this question. Does it matter which programming language is used for the solution? Are the blank lines you show in the example inputs and outputs supposed to be there?

Comment: @RoryDaulton  It doesn't matter  in programming language is used, blank lines in inputs and outputs didn't suppose to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not show any code of your own, I'll give you some ideas without code. If you need more help, show more of your work then I can show you Python code that solves your problem.

Your problem is suitable for [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Wikipedia's definition of this algorithm is

> Backtracking is a general algorithm for finding all (or some) solutions to some [computational problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_problem), notably [constraint satisfaction problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons a candidate ("backtracks") as soon as it  determines that the candidate cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution.

and

> Backtracking can be applied only for problems which admit the concept of a "partial candidate solution" and a relatively quick test of whether it can possibly be completed to a valid solution.

Your problem satisfies those requirements. At each stage you need to choose one of the remaining weights and one of the two pans of the scale. When you place the chosen weight on the chosen pan, you determine if the corresponding letter from the input string is satisfied. If not, you reject the choice of weight and pan. If so, you continue by choosing another weight and pan.

Your overall routine first inputs and prepares the data. It then calls a recursive routine that chooses one weight and one pan at each level. Some of the information needed by each level could be put into mutable global variables, but it would be more clear if you pass all needed information as parameters. Each call to the recursive routine needs to pass:

- the weights not yet used
- the input L/R string not yet used
- the current state of the weights on the pans, in a format that can easily be printed when finalized (perhaps an array of ordered pairs of a weight and a pan)
- the current weight imbalance of the pans. This could be calculated from the previous parameter, but time would be saved by passing this separately. This would be total of the weights on the right pan minus the total of the weights on the left pan (or vice versa).

Your base case for the recursion is when the unused-weights and unused-letters are empty. You then have finished the search and can print the solution and quit the program. Otherwise you loop over all combinations of one of the unused weights and one of the pans. For each combination, calculate what the new imbalance would be if you placed that weight on that pan. If that new imbalance agrees with the corresponding letter, call the routine recursively with appropriately-modified parameters. If not, do nothing for this weight and pan.

You still have a few choices to make before coding, such as the data structure for the unused weights. Show me some of your own coding efforts then I'll give you my Python code.

Be aware that this could be slow for a large number of weights. For `n` weights and two pans, the total number of ways to place the weights on the pans is `n! * 2**n` (that is a factorial and an exponentiation). For `n = 50` that is over `3e79`, much too large to do.  The backtracking avoids most groups of choices, since choices are rejected as soon as possible, but my algorithm could still be slow. There may be a better algorithm than backtracking, but I do not see it. Your problem seems to be designed to be handled by backtracking.

---

Now that you have shown more effort of your own, here is my un-optimized Python 3 code. This works for all the examples you gave, though I got a different valid solution for your third example.

```
def weights_on_pans():
    def solve(unused_weights, unused_tilts, placement, imbalance):
        """Place the weights on the scales using recursive
        backtracking. Return True if successful, False otherwise."""
        if not unused_weights:
            # Done: print the placement and note that we succeeded
            for weight, pan in placement:
                print(weight, 'L' if pan < 0 else 'R')
            return True  # success right now
        tilt, *later_tilts = unused_tilts
        for weight in unused_weights:
            for pan in (-1, 1):  # -1 means left, 1 means right
                new_imbalance = imbalance + pan * weight
                if new_imbalance * tilt > 0:  # both negative or both positive
                    # Continue searching since imbalance in proper direction
                    if solve(unused_weights - {weight},
                             later_tilts,
                             placement + [(weight, pan)],
                             new_imbalance):
                        return True  # success at a lower level
        return False  # not yet successful

    # Get the inputs from standard input. (This version has no validity checks)
    cnt_weights = int(input())
    weights = {int(item) for item in input().split()}
    letters = input()
    # Call the recursive routine with appropriate starting parameters.
    tilts = [(-1 if letter == 'L' else 1) for letter in letters]
    solve(weights, tilts, [], 0)

weights_on_pans()
```

The main way I can see to speed up that code is to avoid the `O(n)` operations in the call to `solve` in the inner loop. That means perhaps changing the data structure of `unused_weights` and changing how it, `placement`, and perhaps `unused_tilts`/`later_tilts` are modified to use `O(1)` operations. Those changes would complicate the code, which is why I did not do them.

Comment: I already calculate number of ways to place the weights on pans and that is why I thought this problem is NP-complete.  Time limit in problem is 0.5 second, so for some points I wrought code with random determination of permutation of weights and random putting them on scale. My code works perfect for small numbers, but when n is 50, my code don't have a chance to generate solution.

Comment: @DjoleSt: I edited my code to remove a minor bug, improve the completion of the program, remove the validity checks on the input, reduce the number of code lines, and make it completely self-contained. My code should be much faster than yours but I cannot guarantee it is fast enough. My code could be speed-optimized by making the parameters to be global variables, but that has other disadvantages. If you really need top speed, you should not be using Python (which has many offsetting advantages).